# How to keep domain name in address bar

Tags: dns

Is there a better way to keep the domain name unaltered in the adress bar besides using a main frame?

Comment: When you try to do what?

Comment: I wanna keep the main domain "http://www.example.com/" in the adress bar all the time while the user is navigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a frame (or some other inner window, via Flash or Silverlight, etc.) really is the only way to do it - if you try to modify the main window's location with JavaScript, it will change the page's location to the URL you specify, so that will not really work either.

You should be mindful of [**RESTful**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) principles - what is the intent for not allowing the URL in the address bar to reflect the true location of the user within the domain?

Comment: Yeah, I know I shouldn't do it, but the client just won't agree with me, so...
Thanks a lot, anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can use AJAX to change the content of the page without changing the address.

However, if the data is located on another domain then the address should change to point to that domain.  Also, it is recommended that the address can be bookmarked so user's can easily return to the data.  The address should reflect the content of the resource it points to.

Comment: You didn't use the name, but in the last part of your comments, you are speaking of RESTful concepts - have a URL always point to a page in a given state and have the state of the page reflected in the URL are part of REST.